# Apple Thunderbolt display not turning on when connected to ASUS Z87 motherboard

Tags: thunderbolt-display, pc

I recently purchased custom build PC with Asus Z87 Expert Thunderbolt motherboard, Intel i7-4790K processor, Sapphire R9 270X 2 GB graphics card, etc.

It's not working with my Apple Thunderbolt display 27″. I have installed Intel Thunderbolt driver as well.

When I connect this PC to the Apple Thunderbolt display, the display won't turn on. I am very disappointed now. Does anybody know how to make it work?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nobody ?? :( :(

Answer (score 1):

**Okay,** I have figured it out myself :)
Feeling extremely happy.

**Steps:**

1. Enter BIOS setting. For most of the computer, you just have to press
   F2 while computer starts.
2. Enter Advance BIOS setting mode.
3. Enable iGPU and Multi-Monitor option in the Graphics section.

**That's it.** Restart your computer and Enjoy the terrific Apple thunderbolt display quality in Windows operating system.

**My PC specs:**

- Motherboard: ASUS Z87 Expert
- CPU: Intel Core i7 4790k
- Discrete GPU: Sapphire R9 270X 2GB Dedicated
- and Apple Thunderbolt Display 27" :)

Any Windows operating System (7/8/8.1) will work but my my operating system is Windows 10 Technical Preview.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Khaled, you do realise that you only use the intel integrated graphics if you plug it in this way, if you want the full power of your graphics card you will need to plug it in the ports on that.

Comment: @dennismuys, How do I do that? Sapphire R9 270X has only HDMI and DP/DV port. No thunderbolt port

Comment: you can buy a adapter tb>dp/dv port or tb>hdmi you won't be able to utilise the camera or usb hub on the display though

Comment: I searched for this kind of cable ( female tb to male hdmi/dp), but could not find anywhere.  Can you suggest any online shopping link? Thanks a lot.

Comment: a simple amazon search for thunderbolt to hdmi gives 321 pages of hits, note that a mini displayport to hdmi cable is exactly the same and can be used too

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently with a new Lenovo Thinkpad X1 carbon, that has two combined USB-3/Thunderbold-3 ports.

When attaching the Apple Thunderbolt display using a Thunderbolt-3 to Thunderbolt-2 adapter (from Apple), the display would be recognized, but did NOT turn on.

I could solve the issue by going into the BIOS and enable BIOS-support for Thunderbolt.
After that it works perfectly (currently running Windows-10 with dual-monitor support.

Regards, JvW